# Merging laravel's Form class with Bootstraps form-group class

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a form in laravel to edit a post using bootstrap:

```
@section('content')
    <form method="PUT" action="{{ URL::route('post.update', array($post->id)) }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usr">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" name="title" value="{{$post->title}}">

            <br>

            <label for="comment">Details:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="detail"
                      placeholder="Write a new post.">"{{$post->message}}"</textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="add">
        </div>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Cancel</a>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">
        </div>
    </form>


@stop
```

It looks like this: [image]

Now, if I use Laravel's Form class, it's much smaller and neater:

```
{{Form::model($post, array('method' => 'PUT', 'route' => array('post.update', $post->id)))}}
{{ Form::label('title', 'Post Title: ') }}
{{ Form::text('title') }}
{{ $errors->first('title') }}
<p></p>
{{ Form::label('message', 'Post Message: ') }}
{{ Form::text('message') }}

{{ $errors->first('message') }}
<p></p>
{{ Form::submit('Update') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

However, this causes the form to look quite ugly:

[image]

So, in short, is there anyway to use Laravel's form class and add boostrap styling/buttons to it? I want the functionality and easy of use of the form class with the visuals of bootstrap.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I can highly recommend [this](https://github.com/dwightwatson/bootstrap-form) package. When installed, you should be able to just replace `Form` with `BootForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class to each input (here is an **exemple**)

```
   {{Form::model($post, array('method' => 'PUT', 'route' => array('post.update', $post->id)))}}
   {!! Form::label('title','Post Title: ', array('class' => 'pull-left'))  !!}
   {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
   {!! Form::label('message','Post Message: ', array('class' => 'pull-left'))  !!}
   {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    <br>
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" role="button">Cancel</a>
   {!! Form::submit('Update',  ['class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right']) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that improved it slightly but it still doesn't look that great.

Comment: Check now, but , im helping you how  to add classes to the form, im not trying to give you the 100% correct form that you are looking for, im showing you how you can make it

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. I'll play around with it and get it right. I noticed that you used "Form::open". Why use that instead of "Form::Model"?

Comment: if i use Form::Model it will throw an exeption because i dont have the model , thats all, i edited the answer, if this answer your question please make this question as answered

Comment: Can we add more than one classes?